# Subtracting unit box from phase of a sinusoidal curve

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

```
DiscretePlot[
  {117 (Cos[
     10 x + 28.58 - .19 UnitBox[100 x - 1] - .19 UnitBox[
     100 x - 10] - .19 UnitBox[100 x - 20] - .19 UnitBox[
     100 x - 35]]^2)}, {x, 0, .40, .001}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Thickness[.004]}, 
  Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig]

I want to subtract the (more than 10th term) unitbox from the phase of             the sinusoidal curve. How could I use `Table` to make the plot shown above.

I used expression given below, but it does not work.

```
Cos[10 x - Table[.19 UnitBox[250 x - s], {s, 1, 10, 1}]]^2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot[117*Cos[
  10 x + 28.58 - .19 *
    Plus @@ (UnitBox[100 x - #] & /@ {1, 10, 20, 35})], {x, 0, 0.40},
  Exclusions -> False]
```

[image: plot]

Have fun!